# firefox equivalent of chrome inspector Resources tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, local-storage, html5-appcache

Is there a firefox equivalent of chrome's inspector "Resources" tab? I am trying to delete something from localStorage for a web site in firefox but it won't go, and the standard settings->clear cahce don't affect it at all.

Comment: Cache control addons? Call `localStorage.clear()` from firebug?

Comment: So there is no native way of checking (or at least clearing) your firefox localstorage??

Comment: `localStorage.clear` method clear localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Check for this: 
Enter about:cache in browser address and see "Offline cache device" section.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox storage inspector lets you see local storage.
This seems to be the closest equivalent to the chrome resource tab.

I had to explicitly enable the tab in the Firefox Develop Tools Options to get it to show.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector